# Title in gnuplot based on array index

Tags: gnuplot

I have an array which has values like:

```
percentile="P5,P10,P20,P25,P50,P75"
```

I'm using for loop for iteration in gnuplot, somewhat like this:

```
plot for [i=2:4] "Stats.data" using (column(1)):(column(i)) title "${percentile[i]}".i
```

What I want is that the titles to be taken up from the percentile array.But this isn't happening.

ERROR:invalid command

Answer (score 3):

if `percentile` is represented as a string in you Gnuplot script, then you might employ the `word` function which extracts the corresponding white-space delimited word from the supplied string (the word index is 1-based)

```
percentile="P5 P10 P20 P25 P50 P75"

plot for [i=2:4] "Stats.data" using (column(1)):(column(i)) w l title word(percentile, i+1)
```